# FileNotFoundError Django on Apache (File Upload)

Tags: django, apache, upload, media

I'm trying to upload files in my development server, but can't make it work. I
keep getting:

```
FileNotFoundError at /select_text
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA\\media\\dados_petroleo.txt'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://agata.pgie.ufrgs.br/select_text
Django Version: 2.0.1
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA\\media\\dados_petroleo.txt'
Exception Location: /home/metis/public_html/AGATA/textMining/TextMining.py in separete_file_sentences, line 30
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/home/metis/public_html/AGATA',
 '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/agataenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 16 Feb 2018 13:19:48 +0000
```

Perhaps it's on `/home/metis/public_html/AGATA\\media\\dados_petroleo.txt'` , that should be `/home/metis/public_html/AGATA/media/dados_petroleo.txt` , but it's using `\\` ...what's going on?

settings.py:

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/metis/public_html/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/metis/public_html/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Could you provide a minimal working example of code in order to reproduce your issue ?

How are you getting/passing your argument from/to your route?

This looks like there is some escaping going on.

First (and probably not the best) idea, would be to replace `"\\"` by `"/"` in your `separete_file_sentences` function, before using it.

This would be more of a quickfix than a real solution TBH.